# Cordova no longer compile Android Apps

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

I have Cordova, NPM, NodeJS, Ant, JDK on my system with the Android ADK in order to build Android Apps.

running the `--version` or `-v` or `-version` flag for all returns expected results

```
NPM = 1.3.10
NodeJS = v0.10.25
Ant = 1.9.3
Java = 1.8.0_72
Cordova = 6.0.0
```

But when I attempt the default cordova hello world program I am unable to build an android app

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

creates the necassary cordova project with the hello dir and returns

```
Creating a new cordova project.
```

no errors so I can cd into hello
within the hello dir adding the android platform returns no errors that I can detect

```
cordova platform add android
```

and this returns,

```
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms/android
    Package: com.example.hello
    Name: HelloWorld
    Activity: MainActivity
    Android target: android-23
Android project created with cordova-android@5.1.0
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" in config.xml. Installing to the project
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist@1" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android

               This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android greater than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do *not* need this plugin since the whitelist will be built in.
```

everything runs as expected to this point, however building the cordova project

```
cordova build android
```

returns the following errors, NB my Android SDK is up to date and already has API 10, 19, and 23 installed

```
ANDROID_HOME=/home/lyndon/Software/android-sdk-linux
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Unzipping /home/lyndon/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.2.1-all/2m8005s69iu8v0oiejfej094b/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip to /home/lyndon/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.2.1-all/2m8005s69iu8v0oiejfej094b
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:160)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:29)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:70)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    ... 3 more
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 1 for command: /home/lyndon/Documents/UCT/iCOMMS/hello/hello/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/lyndon/Documents/UCT/iCOMMS/hello/hello/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: Error code 1 for command: /home/lyndon/Documents/UCT/iCOMMS/hello/hello/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/lyndon/Documents/UCT/iCOMMS/hello/hello/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

If you have an idea of how to troubleshoot this I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: [Google Group of Cordova/Phonegap](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap)

Comment: Try to replace `java8` by `java-7u79` :D

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Mr Neo but it didn't work. I installed java -7u79 with jdk 1.7.0_79 running     `javac -version` confirms this. But I get the exacting errors as previously listed. Also tried this is java -7u80 and the same errors persist